# Dropit Jquery - keep submenu open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using simple DropIt jquery dropdowns - http://dev7studios.com/dropit/

I want to have the submenu box stay open unless clicked outside of the box (.dropit-submenu)
I'm planning to have a form input in dropdown but whenever i click input inside dropdown the whole dropdown closes...

line 40 of js is showing this

```
 // Close if outside click
$(document).on('click', function() {
    settings.beforeHide.call(this);
    $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
    settings.afterHide.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick if you want to use, on div which is popping up you can write onclick="return false;" so this will not go to call jquery other call and after your form submission you can hide the same div.

Comment: can you remove this ".find('.dropit-submenu').hide()"

Answer (score 0):

```
// Close if outside click
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest('.dropit-submenu').length){ return true; }
  settings.beforeHide.call(this);
  $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
  settings.afterHide.call(this);
});
```